# Using duality to prove special case of Fatou's lemma

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $A_n$ is a sequence of events in a probability space, my book calls the following inequalities Fatou's lemma:

$$P(\lim \inf A_n) \leq \lim \inf P(A_n)$$ $$P(\lim \sup A_n) \geq \lim \sup P(A_n)$$

If i didn't do a mistake, i proved the first inequality. The second inequality seems like something dual to the first in some sense, but i'm not able to pinpoint what. Is there a way to quickly prove the second inequality using the first?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Omega$ be the underlying probability space. Then :
$$\limsup A_n = \Omega-\liminf(\Omega-A_n)$$
and therefore :
\begin{align}
P(\limsup A_n) &= 1-P(\liminf \Omega-A_n) \\
&\geq  1-\liminf P(\Omega - A_n) \\
&\geq 1-\liminf (1-P(A_n))\\
&\geq \limsup P(A_n)
\end{align}

Comment: How do you know the last step? I mean, why is $1-\lim inf(1-P(A_n)) \ge \lim sup P(A_n)$ ?